# How to link Firebase account to Google Play Games account

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play-games

I have an Android game that uses Play Games Services. Play Games Services appear to be linked to a specific Google Login. If a player starts the game, it is automatically logged into Play Games.

Now I wish to incorporate Firebase into my game as well, for example to facilitate chat.

How can I use the Play Games `user account` to `create/login` to a Firebase account?

Is there some sort of token Play Games gives me I can just pass onto Firebase?

I am trying to avoid having to use my own backend server, and avoid having the user having to sign in twice in my game, since that is a rather poor user experience.

What are my options? I'm rather stumped on how to approach this.

**-- SOLVED --**

First of all I needed to enable Google Signin from the Firebase auth tab.
Then I used this code in my base activity:

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken("<appidfromfirebase>.apps.googleusercontent.com")
        .build();


mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .enableAutoManage(this, this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addApi(Games.API)
    .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
    .build();


@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.hasConnectedApi(Games.API)) {
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                            GoogleSignInAccount acct = googleSignInResult.getSignInAccount();
                            if (acct == null) {
                                Logger.e("account was null: " + googleSignInResult.getStatus().getStatusMessage());
                                return;
                            }

                            AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(),null);

                            mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(
                                            new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                                    // check task.isSuccessful()
                                                }
                                            });
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the id token for the user to link the Google identity to the [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin).

Build the Google API client with the games config, requesting an ID token.

```
GoogleSignInOptions options = new GoogleSignInOptions
            .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(firebaseClientId)
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Games.API)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, options)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```

Then launch the SignIn Intent:

```
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

And when the result is returned, get the id token and pass it to Firebase.Auth:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result =
                Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(intent);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
          AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
                                          acct.getIdToken(), null);
          FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is.. close enough. I updated the original question to show my final code

Answer (score 0):

Your logged-in Google account in your Android device is usually the one [linked with your GPGS profile](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2954594?hl=en&ref_topic=3114802).

Now to answer your question, follow the [Integrate With Your Play Games Services Project](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/integrate-play-games) guide on how to use Firebase with GPGS.

> When you add Firebase to your Play Game Services project in the Play
>   Developer console, you can:
>
> Get access to Firebase Analytics, a free app measurement solution that
>   provides insight on app usage and user engagement. View your Games
>   events in the Firebase Analytics by logging Play Games events to
>   Firebase.
>
> When you add Firebase to your Play Games Services project, you’re also
>   [linking your Google Play Account to your Firebase
>   project](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6392038?hl=en&ref_topic=6317497).
>
> **Add Firebase to your Play Games Services project**
>
> In the Play Developer Console:
>
> Click Add Firebase on the Game details page of your app Review the
>   policy confirmation, then click Confirm Now Firebase is added to your
>   Play Games Project and your Google Play account is linked to your
>   Firebase project. Next, you will need to add the Firebase SDK to your
>   app's code.
>
> **Add the Firebase SDK to your a**pp
>
> To get started, add Firebase Analytics to your app.
>
> Once you have added the Firebase Analytics SDK to your app, you can
>   begin logging Play Games events.